# css slider plugin stops working after slightest modification

Tags: jquery, html, css

I looked for a slider plugin that shows images when hover over the thumbnails and i found this : http://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/BImgA

Overall, it works great, but there are two main problems.

first, I want to put that thumbnails (.mini) somewhere other than inside the #contenedor, but it stops functioning right after i move the mini divs anywhere but the exact original location.

for instance,

```
<section id="contenedor">

<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>

<ul id="slider">
    <li>
        <div><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
</ul>

</section>
```

this works okay, but

```
<section id="contenedor">



<ul id="slider">
    <li>
        <div><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><p>Ipsum slider</p></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="" height="200" width="600">
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50" width="150"></div>


</section>
```

this is not working.

and the weird thing is that, if i add margin-top or almost anything to the .mini, also stops working.

does anyone know the reason why?

and the thing is that, i want the images inside the slider to auto adjust their size to fit to the div.

I've tried giving slider divs background-image, instead of just inserting images, but it doesn't seem to work.

can anyone help me out?
thanks.

Comment: yes. that's the whole purpose of this question, because it shouldn't really affect the way how the slider works. but for reason it doesn't.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly deleted my comment. But where do you want to display those 150x150 images to hover on it for effect?

Comment: `margin-top: 200px;` already added to `.mini` you can check it out. and you can change it's value

Comment: @MaihanNijat  um, if you take a look into this website, http://ike.co.kr/English/main.html you can see that 150*50 images are on top of the slider image, but i want it to be in the bottom. so i've tried the code above, as well as giving margin-top value to the .mini, but everytime it *stops* working.

Comment: i'll take a look into it one  more time see if i can manage to get it working just by using css and tell you if there's further problem.

Comment: But it is already in the bottom? Isn't it?

Comment: um, okay, the problem is that it stops working if i put that mini divs somewhere other than the original position. see www.http://ike.co.kr/English/main.html. and if anyone can help me out, i would very much appreciate it. thanks.

Comment: @MaihanNijat yes. i just edited the html, and put it into the spot that i want it to be. but notice it stops working as a slider.

Comment: @MarkKang You don't need to make changes in html. You can do using only css. Check my answer.

Comment: @MarkKang Please check the answer and let me know if you need it with the border.

Comment: @MaihanNijat i already checked into your solution, but it gets covered by the other divs. see my website : http://ike.co.kr/English/main.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following styles:

```
#contenedor{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width:600px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.mini{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

With:

```
#contenedor{
    width:600px;
    height: 270px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.mini{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 220px;
    width: 25%;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

I also removed the border from `section` that 150x150 images look outside the box in the bottom.

In your website, you don't have enough space to fit 150x150 four times, therefore I reduced the `width` of images to `122px`.

```
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50px" width="122px"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50px" width="122px"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50px" width="122px"></div>
<div class="mini"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="" height="50px" width="122px"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. but this one also gets covered if i resize and shrink the window height.

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot with window resized because I am resizing it and works fine?

Comment: see this one http://imgur.com/4zWiMcD as the screen resolution does not stretch to the 1080, the .minis are covered by other layers below. can you find any solution this this problem?

Comment: @MarkKang Please use the above `HTML`

Comment: Thanks. but this is what happens if i use your code... http://ike.co.kr/English/main.html

Comment: It is not edit it yet. Copy the code again. I still see the `width: 150`. Use only `HTML`.

Comment: i've tried the one above, and im still getting the same problem. i don't think it's solvable by just using css.

Comment: For your website, use your own CSS code you have, and do not copy the one I provided because it is for the `codpin` version. And for your website use only the `HTML` code I provided. I inspected your website and changed the width and it worked.

Comment: @MarkKang Can you reverse it back to the first version (shrink issue one)?

Comment: @MarkKang there are no buttons 150x150 on above?

Comment: @MarkKang But before you had buttons on top of it, now there are no buttons.

Comment: i moved it to the bottom by giving .mini position:absolute, and bottom:0. seems like it's working. but only problem is it gets covered. so i wanted to use position:relative instead of absolute, but that doesn't work on this css slider.

Comment: i just fixed that problem by giving min-height to 600px. thanks for your interest and i hope i get help from you again from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top: 200px;` from `.mini` and add `margin-top:55px;` to `#slider{` will make `150 X 50` image on top of big image.

I don't think you need to make changes in HTML. You can do it using css itself.

**[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgwjVB)**

Comment: thanks, ketan, but the probelm is that, the mini divs are still inside the container, which gets covered if the website is accessed by lower screen resolution. so, i would rather put that mini divs completely outside the #contenedor and somewhere clearly visible.

Comment: @MarkKang Your Jquery plugins not allow you to do that. You should then make changes in Jquery plugin itself.

Comment: @MarkKang You can put http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrzvyr this way mini div to below slider div but CSS will not allow to slide the previous sibling to slide on hover next slibling.